# Issues with to_string

Tags: c++, string

I get the following error when I try to compile like this.
    c++ date.cc -std=c++11

"*date.cc:41:40: error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'*"

This is the code:

```
if ( _month < 1 || _month > 12 )
{
throw domain_error{"Month " + std::to_string(_month) + " doesn't exist!"};
}
```

If i remove std:: I get:
    *"'to_string' was not declared in this scope"*

My version is:
gcc version 5.3.0 (GCC)

any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

`std::to_string` is defined in header `<string>`.

You need to add `#include <string>`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Comment: @sockevalley Why don't I see it in the code you have posted?

Comment: @sockevalley Please provide a [Minimal but Complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)